# mongodb query for string separated column of integer consist data join with other collection matched specific value of integer

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections 
1.clinic

[subspeciality column entries are in "38,39,40,41" format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvt7Z.png)

where as my other collections 
2. subspeciality 
[consist of id in integer form,like 1,2,3,4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB7yW.png)

I want to join this two with column name called subspeciality from 1st collections and id from 2nd collections,to print name(string) from second collection.

Please help me to solve above issue.

Thank in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried anything till now and any error you got? If yes, post it here as well. For joining two collections in Mongo, you can use $lookup https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Thanks I solve this problem with mongodb $split operator